# Microsoft OAuth2 SMTP

Tags: python, oauth, smtp, azure-ad-msal, smtplib

I am trying to build an application that sends emails from my Microsoft office email account, in Python using SMTP for sending with OAuth2 for authentication. The authentication is not working, I am getting `reply: retcode (535); Msg: b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [LO2P265CA0061.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]'`

I have created an AAD application on azure and downloaded the example flask app that is offered there after setting up the credentials, which I understand is just this [repo](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapp)

I have used this app (downloaded from the AAD portal with my secret in it) and tried to use the given token for SMTP authentication, using the information from

- [Microsoft docs 1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-8361e398-8af4-4e97-b147-6c6c4ac95353?ui=en-us&rs=en-gb&ad=gb)
- [Microsoft docs 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth)

Logging in with my office email account works and the `/graphcall` works as well. However the SMTP authentication is not working, I am receiving `reply: retcode (535); Msg: b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [LO2P265CA0061.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]'` from it.

The Scope of the token that I am asking for is `SCOPE = ["User.ReadBasic.All", "https://outlook.office.com/SMTP.Send"]` and the app has `SMTP.send` turned on in the config file

Here is a class extending `smtplib.SMTP` that I have written based  on those:

```py
import smtplib
import base64


class MicrosoftSMTP(smtplib.SMTP):
    def __init__(self, host="smtp.office365.com", port=587, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(host=host, port=port, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def encode_auth_token(username, token):
        just_a_str = f"user={username}\x01auth=Bearer {token}\x01\x01"
        xoauth2_token = base64.b64encode(just_a_str.encode())

        return xoauth2_token

    def authenticate(self, username, token):
        self.helo()

        # first step, we
        code, msg = self.docmd("auth", "XOAUTH2")
        if code != 334:
            raise Exception(msg.decode())

        # send the token
        self.send(self.encode_auth_token(username, token))
```

and the code to connect with the credentials from the app here, and adding a page where I display the token json for a sanity check:

```py
@app.route("/send_to_self")
def send_to_self():
    token = _get_token_from_cache(app_config.SCOPE)
    if not token:
        return redirect(url_for("login"))

    # connect to the server
    connection = MicrosoftSMTP()
    connection.set_debuglevel(True)  # for output
    connection.starttls()
    connection.authenticate(
        # same as session["user"]["preferred_username"]
        token["id_token_claims"]["preferred_username"],
        token["access_token"],
    )

    # ... would write an email here with connection.sendmail( ... )

    connection.quit()

    return render_template(
        "send_to_self.html",
        data=token,
        data_session=session["flow"],
        data_user=session["user"],
    )
```

The authentication is failing, here is the full log:

```
send: 'ehlo 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa\r\n'
reply: b'250-LO2P265CA0516.outlook.office365.com Hello [<A.GENERAL.IP>]\r\n'
reply: b'250-SIZE 157286400\r\n'
reply: b'250-PIPELINING\r\n'
reply: b'250-DSN\r\n'
reply: b'250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\r\n'
reply: b'250-STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: b'250-8BITMIME\r\n'
reply: b'250-BINARYMIME\r\n'
reply: b'250-CHUNKING\r\n'
reply: b'250 SMTPUTF8\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'LO2P265CA0516.outlook.office365.com Hello [<A.GENERAL.IP>]\nSIZE 157286400\nPIPELINING\nDSN\nENHANCEDSTATUSCODES\nSTARTTLS\n8BITMIME\nBINARYMIME\nCHUNKING\nSMTPUTF8'
send: 'STARTTLS\r\n'
reply: b'220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready\r\n'
reply: retcode (220); Msg: b'2.0.0 SMTP server ready'
send: 'helo 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa\r\n'
reply: b'250 LO2P265CA0516.outlook.office365.com Hello [<A.GENERAL.IP>]\r\n'
reply: retcode (250); Msg: b'LO2P265CA0516.outlook.office365.com Hello [<A.GENERAL.IP>]'
send: 'auth XOAUTH2\r\n'
reply: b'334 \r\n'
reply: retcode (334); Msg: b''
send: b'dX......EB'
send: 'quit\r\n'
reply: b'535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [LO2P265CA0516.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]\r\n'
reply: retcode (535); Msg: b'5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful [LO2P265CA0516.GBRP265.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM]'
```

### things I have cheeked:

1. we have SMTP allowed for this mailbox
2. the token has the SMTP allowed
3. the XOAUTH2 token encoder's output matches that of the example on the website

FYI the token data looks like this, with the tokens and username removed

```json
{
    "access_token": "ey<...>aw",
    "client_info": "ey<...>In0",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "ext_expires_in": 3599,
    "id_token": "ey<...>jQ",
    "id_token_claims": {
        "aud": "8<...>9",
        "exp": 1634319637,
        "iat": 1634315737,
        "iss": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/5<...>1/v2.0",
        "name": "<Name of the user>",
        "nbf": 1634315737,
        "nonce": "c1<...>d0",
        "oid": "cd<...>1b",
        "preferred_username": "user.name@company.com",
        "rh": "0.A<...>As.",
        "sub": "2w<...>ww",
        "tid": "50<...>31",
        "uti": "8W<...>AA",
        "ver": "2.0"
    },
    "refresh_token": "0.A<...>4Y",
    "scope": "openid profile SMTP.Send User.ReadBasic.All email",
    "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

Comment: in the meantime I found that [python O365](https://github.com/O365/python-o365) can perform the same tasks without the need for SMTP and can send emails natively

Answer (score -1):

1. Disable the Azure Security Default by toggling the Enable Security Default to No:

   - Sign in to the Azure portal as a security administrator, conditional access administrator, or Global administrator.
   - Browse to Azure Active Directory -> Properties.
   - Select Manage security defaults.
   - Set the Enable security defaults toggle to No.
   - Select save.
2. Exclude the user from a Conditional Access policy that blocks legacy Authentication:

   - Sign in to the Azure portal as a Security administrator, Conditional Access administrator, or Global administrator.
   - Browse to Azure Active Directory > Security > Conditional Access.
   - In the policy that blocks legacy Authentication, exclude the mailbox being used under Users and Groups > Exclude.
   - Select Save.

You should use as SMTP server: **apicalsolutions-com.mail.protection.outlook.com** with **port 25**. As user use any user of your domain. Even if it has no linked mailbox you can use to for login.

Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/Exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365#settings-for-direct-send).

Comment: Do I take it this means using Basic Authentication and not Oauth2?

Comment: Turning off the security policy is not always possible. And should not be advised right off the bat.